# Limit excerpts of post types

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have two post types, the regular posts and a custom post type. Everything is working fine and I show only 5 posts. One as a full post and four as excerpts. The problem I have is that the excerpts is showing the latest posts, independent of post category. I want to show two of the posts and two of the custom post type.

```
$args  = array(
    'post_type' => array( 'post', 'tutorial' ),

);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) :
    $count = 0;
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
        if ( $count == 0 ) { ?>

            <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
            <?php the_content();

            $count ++;

        } else { ?>
            <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
            <?php the_excerpt();
        }
    endwhile;

endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Expected output should be the latest post as a full post, as it is working now. Then it should display the two latest posts of post type post and two latest posts of post type tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basicly you only need to sort by posttype

```
$args  = array(
    'post_type' => array( 'post', 'tutorial' ),
    'orderby' => 'post_type',
    'order'   => 'ASC',
);
```

If you want to keep the sorting of date as a secondary sort this should work (not tested).

```
$args  = array(
    'post_type' => array( 'post', 'tutorial' ),
    'orderby' => array ('post_type' => 'ASC', 'order' => 'DESC' ),
);
```

For more information check the [WP_Query documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters)

Keep in mind that if you have 5 posts newer then any of your tutorials, none will show.
To guarantee 3 posts and 2 tutorials you will need to split the code in 2 `wp_query` loops with the `posts_per_page` parameter.

Comment: OK, it's the last part of our answer that I'm after. I was hoping I could do it with one ```wp_query``` but then I will have to use 2.

Comment: I get that but there is no reliable way to do it with one. Good caching is your friend (a friend with issues, but still)